# Getting nearest index in Numpy

Tags: arrays, numpy, indexing

import numpy as np

I have a given array (a):

```
a = np.array([[99,2,3,4,99],
              [6,7,8,99,10]])
```

I have 3 reference arrays (b,c,and d):

```
b = np.array([[99,12,13,14,99],
              [16,17,99,99,20]])

c = np.array([[21,22,23,24,99],
              [26,27,99,99,30]])

d = np.array([[31,32,33,34,35],
              [36,37,99,99,40]])
```

The reference arrays are given together in this form:

`references = np.array([b,c,d])`

I have to replace the value '99' in a given array 'a' using the nearest index
value from the reference arrays if 'non 99' value is available.

The expected answer is:

```
answer = np.array([[21,2,3,4,35],
              [6,7,8,99,10]])
```

What is the **fastest** way of doing it?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could use [`np.select`](http://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy/reference/generated/numpy.select.html):

```
import numpy as np

a = np.array([[99,2,3,4,99],
              [6,7,8,99,10]])

b = np.array([[99,12,13,14,99],
              [16,17,99,99,20]])

c = np.array([[21,22,23,24,99],
              [26,27,99,99,30]])

d = np.array([[31,32,33,34,35],
              [36,37,99,99,40]])

references = np.array([b,c,d])

choices = np.concatenate([a[None, ...], references])
conditions = (choices != 99)

print(np.select(conditions, choices, default=99))
```

yields

```
[[21  2  3  4 35]
 [ 6  7  8 99 10]]
```